# string matching - best/worst case big-Oh complexity

Tags: pattern-matching, time-complexity, big-o

I'm a bit stuck on this and don't really understand how to solve it. I've looked at YouTube et al. and can't understand how to answer this.

```py
def PatternMatch(text, searchspace):
    for pattern in searchspace:
          for offset in range(text.length):
              match = True
              for cmp in range(min(pattern.length,text.length-offset)):
                  if (text[offset+cmp] != pattern[cmp]):
                      match = False
                      break
              if (match) return offset
    return -1
```

This algorithm returns the offset of the first occurrence of any pattern in an array of k > 0 patterns P in a text T and -1 if no pattern in P occurs in T. P is of the form `["string","string","striiing"]`

If we assume that the algorithm is only called when the length of the shortest pattern in P is less than or equal to the length of T, what is the best and worst case big-Oh complexity of PatternMatch? How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Assuming this is meant to by Python-y pseudocode, your code is incorrect because it tries to both zero-index and one-index (you start at 0 but check <= length, meaning that you'll go out of bounds). Also, s+j < T.length is a requirement for validity. And I would recommend using more semantic variable names for your code like "searchspace", "target". This isn't conclusive, but this looks like O(n^2k) to me, and I don't know if best/worst case is particularly useful here, but I think it's O(n) and O(n^2k)

Comment: @HoldenRohrer Oh yes thank you for spotting the mistakes. Also, why would it be O(n^2k)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This does vary quite a bit based on the sizes of the pattern and the tested strings. I'm assuming that both are of length n (for computational simplicity, since the actual case should have the same time complexity) and there are k strings being tested
Each character comparison takes O(1) time, and you perform, per string being matched, n string comparisons of length 1..n (i.e. 1..n character comparisons). This is (n^2+n)/2 comparisons = O(n^2). Since there are k of these tests, the complexity is O(n^2k).

Comment: What does `n` denote ?

Comment: My -1 because the answer is incomplete, superficial and wrong at places.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume `k` patterns of equal length `m` and a text of length `n`.

The best case seems easy: if the first comparison with the first pattern succeeds immediately, the answer is returned after `m` character comparisons, where `m` is the length of the first pattern. Anyway, you could get a faster result if all pattern tests concluded "no match" as soon as possible, which can be achieved in `n-m+1` character comparisons, hence after `k(n-m+1)` comparisons in total. Though unlikely, `k(n-m+1) < m` is possible.

The worst case is a little more difficult. We can imagine that it occurs when the match fails for all patterns, so that `k` matches need to be performed. Now the maximal time to conclude a mismatch is when all offsets lead to a failure, while the string comparisons are carried as far as possible.

This occurs when you search a pattern like `xxxxxxxy` inside `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`: the string comparisons must always be performed in full.

So we have a total worst-case of `k(n-m+1)m` character comparisons. If the lengths are not constant, precise analysis becomes pretty difficult.